# Labeled continue statement within while loop

Tags: java

The following simple examples cause compile-time error. But It's not clear why.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int i = 0;
    d:
    {
        System.out.println("d");
    }
    while(i < 10){

        i++;
        continue d;

    }
}
```

--and--

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int i = 0;
    d:
    {
        System.out.println("d");
        while(i < 10){
            i++;
            continue d;
        }
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/xInSBL)**

But the following works fine:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int i = 0;
    d:
    while(i < 10){
        {
            System.out.println("d");
        }
        i++;
        continue d;

    }
}
```

Does it allow to tranfer control to the only `while`, `for` or `do` statement? It doesn't say in the **[JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.16)**. What it actual says is:

> A continue statement with label Identifier attempts to transfer
>   control to the enclosing labeled statement (§14.7) that has the same
>   Identifier as its label; that statement, which is called the continue
>   target, then immediately ends the current iteration and begins a new
>   one.

Comment: It only work for iteration statements. but `+1` for marking that jls has not specified such an important information.

Comment: Very interesting. As pointed out by other replies, your working case falls into the case of common usage of the continue statement in java, which means to skip the remaining operations in a loop and start at once with the next iteration.
The example in the JLS documentation use labels and "continue" the way you want to use them, namely as goto, but it does not go out of its current scope, as you do in your broken case. I will test some more in this direction. Thank you for this example!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `continue` means go to the start of a loop.  So when you `continue` to a label, the label has to be on a loop.  (It is not a goto statement ...)

---

> Does it allow to tranfer control to the only while, for or do statement? It doesn't say in the JLS.

Actually, it does say.

Here's what [JLS 14.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.16) (Java 8 revision) *really* says:

> "A continue statement with label Identifier attempts to transfer control to the enclosing labeled statement (§14.7) that has the same Identifier as its label; that statement, which is called the continue target, then immediately ends the current iteration and begins a new one.
>
> To be precise, a continue statement with label Identifier always completes abruptly, the reason being a continue with label Identifier.
>
> **The continue target must be a while, do, or for statement, or a compile-time error occurs.**"

(Bolded in original!)

The bolded sentence says that the statement that the label is attached to (referred to as the "continue target") has to be a loop statement of some kind.

Comment: `A continue statement must refer to a label within the immediately enclosing method, constructor, initializer, or lambda body.` There are no non-local jumps. If no labeled statement with Identifier as its label in the immediately enclosing method, constructor, initializer, or lambda body contains the continue statement, a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: That is true.  But spec section I quoted is more explicit than that.

Answer (score 3):

> ***[JLS 14.16](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.16)***
>
> A continue statement may occur **only in a while, do, or for statement (iteration statements)**;
>
> *The continue target must be a while, do, or for statement, or a compile-time error occurs.*

---

> A continue statement with label Identifier ***attempts to transfer
>   control to the enclosing labeled statement*** [(§14.7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) that has the same
>   Identifier as its label; that statement, **which is called the continue
>   target,** ***then immediately ends the current iteration and begins a new
>   one.***

---

> A continue statement **must refer to a label within the immediately
>   enclosing method, constructor, or initializer.** *There are no non-local
>   jumps.* If no labeled statement with Identifier as its label in the
>   immediately enclosing method, constructor, or initializer contains the
>   continue statement, *a compile-time error occurs*.

Comment: You are linking to a spec for Java 7.

Comment: Not out of date.  But the Java 8 spec refers specifically to this very situation.

Comment: (I didn't check to see if the wording is identical in the two versions.  But I think one should use the latest spec on principle ... unless the question specifically asks about one version of Java.)

Comment: @StephenC Yes!absolutely agree.I will defeneitly use the latest one in future :) :).